# busybox error while building using yocto

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto, systemd, busybox

I am building images for raspberrypi as per the steps updated at "https://raspinterest.wordpress.com/2016/11/30/yocto-project-on-raspberry-pi-3/".

I am getting following error for while doing do_package for busybox.

> ERROR: busybox-1.24.1-r0 do_package: Function failed:
>   SYSTEMD_SERVICE_busybox-syslog value busybox-syslog.service does not
>   exist

Can you help to understand and fix this issue.

Comment: I suggest you to update your environment to latest Rocko branch (Krogoth is a little bit old). Problem is that there is a misconfiguration between systemd and busybox, you can read [this](https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2015-February/023734.html) for more details.

Comment: After referring the link [ https://lists.yoctoproject.org/pipermail/yocto/2015-February/023734.html ], by adding "SYSTEMD_PACKAGES=""" in "poky/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox_1.24.1.bb" the build is success. In the busybox config "poky/meta/recipes-core/busybox/busybox/defconfig" file syslog, systemd are enabled. As per the link syslog build might be disabled, any suggestion where the syslog build can be disabled ?

Comment: A good way to investigate is with `bitbake -e [recipe] | egrep '^[A-Z][A-Z_]*='`. You also can check recipe overload/appends with `bitbake-layers show-appends`, `bitbake-layers show-overlayed`